# How to prevent notifications from firing to not logged users?

Tags: javascript, java, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud database and Firebase functions. I have the following code which sends a notification once was executed by firebase functions:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: started");
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: message is: " + remoteMessage.getData());

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "User is logged out. Will not fire notification");
        return;
    }

    String payloadDisplayStatus = remoteMessage.getData().get("display_status");
    if (payloadDisplayStatus == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: did not find a display status field");
        return;
    }

    buildAdminBroadcastNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {
    super.onDeletedMessages();
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user == null) {
        return; // Failed to get current user
    }
    final String usersEmail = user.getEmail();
    final String usersPhoneNumber = user.getPhoneNumber();
    if (usersEmail != null && !(usersEmail.isEmpty())) {
        db.collection("managers").document(usersEmail).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "addOnSuccessListener:success");
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            List<DocumentReference> groups = (List<DocumentReference>) documentSnapshot.get("groups");
                            if (groups == null || groups.size() == 0) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to fetch the manager group");
                                return;
                            }
                            DocumentReference connectedGroupDocumentRef = groups.get(0);
                            connectedGroupDocumentRef.collection("managers").document(usersEmail).update("tokens", FieldValue.arrayUnion(token));
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Document does not exist");
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "addOnSuccessListener:failed", exception);
            }
        });
    } else if (usersPhoneNumber != null && !(usersPhoneNumber.isEmpty())) {
        db.collection("employees").document(usersPhoneNumber).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "addOnSuccessListener:success");
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            List<DocumentReference> groups = (List<DocumentReference>) documentSnapshot.get("groups");
                            if (groups == null || groups.size() == 0) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to fetch the volunteer group");
                                return;
                            }
                            DocumentReference connectedGroupDocumentRef = groups.get(0);
                            connectedGroupDocumentRef.collection("employees").document(usersPhoneNumber).update("tokens", FieldValue.arrayUnion(token));
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Document does not exist");
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "addOnSuccessListener:failed", exception);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The functions `index.js` file has the following piece of code which executes the `onMessageReceived` method:

```
let tokens = deliveredUserData.tokens;
const payload = {
    data: {
        display_status: 'admin_broadcast',
        notification_type: 'DELIVERED',
        message: deliveredUser.message,
        receiver_path: deliveredUserDoc.ref.toString()
    }
};
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
```

The `tokens` is an array of all tokens of the user. My app contains two types of people - `managers` and `employees`. If user connected to `manager`, log out and then connected to `employee` (or the other way around), the notification will be sent to both of them, even though only one of the is actually connected. How can I prevent it from happening in?

**EDIT**: Is there some way to check if a token is of the connected user? something like:

```
if (!(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().verifyToken(token))) {
    return; // Invalid token
}
```

That way I could pass the `token` from js to java and check it. But I didn't find a way to do it **without SDK**.